# performSelector: withObject: afterDelay not executing for MBProgressHUD

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, mbprogresshud

I have the following method for a MBProgressHUD:

```
 [progressHUD performSelector:@selector(hide:) 
                   withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] 
                   afterDelay:kMessageHidingDelay];
```

the delay is 2.0 here, however it's not calling hide after 2.0 seconds. I tried to put a breakpoint in the hide function and it's not getting there. Any idea? Here's the full code:

```
progressHUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:viewToAttach];

            // Add HUD to screen
            [viewToAttach addSubview:progressHUD];
            progressHUD.labelText = @"Logging In";
            progressHUD.removeFromSuperViewOnHide = YES;
            // Show the HUD while the provided method executes in a new thread

            [progressHUD show:YES];
```

Comment: why don't you use: - (void)hide:(BOOL)animated afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay; ?

Comment: I don't have that function in my MBProgressHUD... I think this is an issue in my code and has to do with threading, as when the HUD is spinning, I am doing something and when that something is simplified this does it's job perfectly. Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in your version of MBProgressHUD. Get the latest source from here: https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD and try it. Also, make sure not to call UI methods from non UI threads! If you call your delayed methods from another thread than that's your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be try to perform selector on Main thread (all UI changes must be done on main thread)?
    `performSelectorOnMainThread:`

Answer (score 0):

To Show MBProgressHUD Use this Code:-

```
  HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] init];

  [self.view addSubview:HUD];

  HUD.delegate = self;

  [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(myTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];

  where myTask is

   - (void)myTask 
  {
     "Your Code"
  }
```

And too Hide the MBProgressHud

```
 - (void)hudWasHidden:(MBProgressHUD *)hud
    {
       // Remove HUD from screen when the HUD was hidded
       [HUD removeFromSuperview];
       [HUD release];
   HUD = nil;
   }
```

And If you Want to Show Hud With Your CostomView Then Use This Code

```
   HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] init];

[self.view addSubview:HUD];

// Make the customViews 37 by 37 pixels for best results (those are the bounds of the build-in progress indicators)
HUD.customView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your Image Name.png"]] autorelease];

// Set custom view mode
HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;

HUD.delegate = self;

HUD.labelText = @"Completed";

[HUD show:YES];

[HUD hide:YES afterDelay:3];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you have to hide the `MBProgressHud`

```
[progressHUD hide:YES];
```